# Router stopped sharing the internet

Tags: router, modem

Long time ago everything was working perfectly but one day it stopped working! I have an ASUS WL530g V2 router, and a modem from Cisco, my internet provider is KABEL BW, I live in Germany. The connection doesn't require any information to connect, it connects automatically. I am able to connect with the router but it doesn't give me internet from the modem. When I enter 192.168.1.1 I get the following:

> Internet Connection Status
>
> Type:     Automatic IP
>
> Status:   Disconnected
>
> Reason:   lost IP from server

I have tried a lot of things but it simply doesn't work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to contact the ISP and have them confirm everything is working. IT could be the modem is faulty, it could be a technician unplugged you at the street by accident, it could be a billing issue. It could also take several hours for the ISP to renew your IP lease, so constant switching on and off the equipment to reset may not fix it.